# Showing that injective limit is a local ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, local-rings

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be a space with functions(*) such that every stalk $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is local. Furthermore let $Y\subset X$
be an irreducible subset.

Now if we define $\mathcal{U}$ to be set of all open subsets $U\subset X$ with $U\cap Y
\neq\emptyset$, then we have $U,V\in\mathcal{U}$ implies $U\cap V\in\mathcal{U}$ and
we get the $k$-algebra
$$\mathcal{O}_{X,Y}:=\varinjlim_{U\in\mathcal{U}}\mathcal{O}_X(U).$$
My question is, is this $k$-algebra local (as a ring)? I have tried to find candidates for a maximal ideal but did not found anything promising.

Any help/ hint/ advice is very much appreciated!

(*) By this I mean a topological space $X$ with a sheaf of $k$-algebras $\mathcal{O}_X$ such that for every open $U\subset X$ $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is a subalgebra of the $k$-algebra of all $k$-valued functions on $X$.

$\textbf{Edit:}$ Following the comment of KReiser, I first looked at the case $Y=\{y\}$. There $\mathcal{O}_{X,Y}$ reduces to the stalk at $y$ and the ring is local by assumption. I had difficulties defining a map $\mathcal{O}_{X,Y}\to k$ for general irreducible $Y$. But then I
noticed, that $k=k(\{y\})$ is the function field of the space $\{y\}$. Now I am trying to find a surjective $k$-algebra map
$$\mathcal{O}_{X,Y}\to k(Y),$$
but again, I am stuck...

Comment: Try generalizing what happens when $Y$ is a point - you know what the maximal ideal there is, right?

Comment: @KReiser. Thanks for the quick reply! If $Y$ is a point, then the maximal ideal would be the kernel of the evaluation map, right? I'll try what you suggested.

Comment: @KReiser. I am trying to find an analogue of this map, when $Y$ is more than just a poinst, but I don't really see any possibility...

Comment: To find a map out of a colimit, you need only define compatible maps out of each $\mathcal O_X(U)$. Can you think of any maps $\mathcal O_X(U) \longrightarrow k(Y)$? As you correctly noted, for a point you're looking at the evaluation at $y$ map. You can't evaluate at a whole subset $Y$ but what can you do?

Comment: @paulblartmathcop sorry for the very late reply! For $U\in\mathcal{U}$ we have that $k(Y)=\text{qf}\left(\mathcal{O}_X|_YY(U\cap Y)\right)$. But it seems that this gives me an injective map.

Comment: One more hint, then I'll post an answer if you're still in the thick of it: when $Y$ is a point, the maximal ideal admits a description as $(U,f:U\to k)$ so that $U\cap \{y\}\neq \emptyset$ and $f(y)=0$, right? How can you alter this to fit our current situation?

Comment: @KReiser Nope, I don't get it... seems as I am mentally completely blocked. An answer from you would be very much appreciated!

Comment: That map is injective, but you're taking the colimit of all of them, and the colimit could no longer be injective. It could also be surjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximal ideal is the collection of functions $(U,f:U\to k)$ such that $f(y)=0$ for all $y\in Y\cap U$. These are precisely the non-units of the ring, as the way to construct an inverse for any $(U,f:U\to k)$ is to take $(U\setminus f^{-1}(0),1/f)$ where $1/f$ is defined point-wise. It's easy to check that the sum of any two functions of this form (after restricting to a common domain of definition) is again of this form, so by the characterization of a local ring as one where $1\neq 0$ and the sum of two non-units is a non-unit, we're done.